# iOS : pass data from view controller to Detail view controller return null in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, model-view-controller

I have json file, I can print all the informations to my `Log`, from this json I show different location in my map, when I click on annotation button I have to show `detailview`, I can show my detail `views` but my data is null, would you please help me in this implementation, Thanks in advance!

Here is my method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchData];
}


-(void)fetchData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASED_URL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply 
 length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];



    NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         
    NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // handle the error
    }

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {
        // retrieve latitude and longitude from the dictionary entry

        location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

        // create the annotation
        MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;

        newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        newAnnotation.title = dictionary[@"applicant"];
        newAnnotation.subtitle = dictionary[@"company"];
        newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"];
        newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];
        newAnnotation.coordinate = location;

        [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
}
```

I Have a method that should pass data to my detail view

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil 
bundle:nil];
    detail.status.text = annotation.status;
    NSLog(@"status is%@",annotation.status );

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

In my Log I have: status is Active

but in my detail view Log I have Null

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : ViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.status.text = _status.text;
    NSLog(@"Status is %@",_status );
    NSLog(@"Status is %@ ",self.status.text);
 }
```

My status print is : Status is null 
Status is null

Update:Here is my label

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
```

Comment: Have you tried with opening VC using storyboard identifier?

Comment: I told you how to fix this in your previous question. If you didn't understand you should have asked for more help, not re-posted.

Comment: @rdelmar please more help, please write you solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a string, not try to set the label's text in ViewController, because the detail controller's view hasn't been loaded at the time you try to do that. The label will be nil. In DetailController, create a string property,

```
@interface DetailViewController : ViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *passedInString;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.status.text = self.passedInString;
 }
```

In ViewController, pass the string,

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil 
bundle:nil];
    detail.passedInString = annotation.status;
    NSLog(@"status is%@",annotation.status );

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

// detail's viewDidLoad invoked here!

detail.status.text = annotation.status;
```

It's about timing. The instance's status.text is set after viewDidLoad invoked.

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil text:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil text:(NSString *)text
{
    if(self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.status.text = text;
    }
    return self;
}
```

What about this? For sure, you have to instantiate you viewController like...

```
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil text:annotation.status];
```

Comment: What's the difference between OP's code and your code?

Comment: @trick14 Thank you for your comment, what is the solution now?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I added a comment to explain when viewDidLoad is invoked.

Comment: @SaraShumika It will be `annotation.status`. The code I appended is send the NSString as a parameter. You don't need to set it at viewDidLoad.

Comment: @SaraShumika What about log at viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? I'm sure that `self.status.text` is not null.

Comment: @SaraShumika Are you sure that `self.status` is not nil?

Comment: @SaraShumika `My status print is : Status is null Status is null`. This is what you said on your original question. self.status is null or not null?

Comment: @SaraShumika If the label is null, the IBOutlet must be wrong. Check it again.

Comment: @SaraShumika If your IBOutleted UILabel is ok, self.status must not be null. Now, the self.status is null. It means your IBOutlet is wrong somehow. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @SaraShumika OK, I found something weird. Do you have DetailViewController.xib file in your project? If so, `DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil text:annotation.status];` is the correct way to instantiate. If not, the `self.status` can't be IBOutlet.

Comment: @trick14 I found somthing rightnow it is not null It is just Label

Answer (score 0):

Create one NSString in your `DetailViewController` header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *passData;
```

your `viewDidLoad` in `DetailViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.status.text = _passData;
}
```

your `mapView method` in your `viewController`

```
detail.passData = annotation.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign storyboard identifier in Identity inspector to your `DetailViewController`

and use it:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];;
    detail.status.text = annotation.status;
    NSLog(@"status is%@",annotation.status );

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this , i think status label property not dropped from storyboard or nib file . thats y its null. please check

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
     DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     detail.status= annotation.status;
     NSLog(@"status is%@",annotation.status );
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

and

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : ViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *status;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"Status is %@",_status );
}
```

Comment: I had all these NSLOG in my question so what is new?

Comment: @SaraShumika note i had changed type from uilabel to nsstring of variable Status.